# Displaying Errors in online c compiler

Tags: php, c, compiler-errors

Hi all I have a c compiler up and running shows the output but the problem is that it dosen't show errors....

```
      shell_exec("gcc xyz.c -o ab.out ");

      $output=exec("./ab.out");
      echo $output;
```

So it is showing output but not any errors occurred while compiling.
Any help is duly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, the return value of `exec` is just the last line from the result of the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any error output from the command you run will go to STDERR and none of the exec, shell_exec functions will provide you that. One way is to redirect it

```
exec("gcc test.c 2>&1", $out);
```

The most cleaner way is to use [proc_open](http://php.net/proc_open) function.

```
$descriptorspec = array(
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout
   2 => array("pipe", "w") // stderr 
);

$process = proc_open('gcc test.c', $descriptorspec, $pipes);

if (is_resource($process)) {
    $stderr = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
    $stdout = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);
    $return_value = proc_close($process);
}
```

Comment: Will it redirect to the .out file?

Comment: Yes. if you use it that way. `exec("gcc test > out.log 2>&1")`.  See the advanced example with `proc_open`